# How do I add a couple of options to my addin menu?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

Im really struggling with this. I want to create an item in the tools menu so that I have...

```
tools -->  myaddin  --> my option 1
                    --> my option 2
                    --> my option 3
```

I just cant work out how Im meant to do it. Its really annoying there isnt really information about it that seems to just go over how to add items...

The code I have already is what the addin library creates....

```
public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode,
    object addInInst, ref Array custom)
{
  _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
  _addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;
  if(connectMode == ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_UISetup)
  {
    object []contextGUIDS = new object[] { };
    Commands2 commands = (Commands2)_applicationObject.Commands;

    //Place the command on the tools menu.
    //Find the MenuBar command bar, which is the top-level command bar holding all
    // the main menu items:
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBar menuBarCommandBar = 
        ((Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBars)
            _applicationObject.CommandBars)["MenuBar"];

    //Find the Tools command bar on the MenuBar command bar:
    CommandBarControl toolsControl = menuBarCommandBar.Controls["Tools"];


    //same thing just as a popup
    CommandBarPopup toolsPopup = (CommandBarPopup)toolsControl;


    //This try/catch block can be duplicated if you wish to add multiple commands to
    // be handled by your Add-in,
    // just make sure you also update the QueryStatus/Exec method to include the new
    // command names.
    try
    {
      //Add a command to the Commands collection:
      Command command = commands.AddNamedCommand2(_addInInstance, "Switch",
          "Switch", "Executes the command for Switch", true, 59, ref contextGUIDS,
          (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported+
              (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled,
          (int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStylePictAndText,
          vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);

      //Add a control for the command to the tools menu:
      if((command != null) && (toolsPopup != null)) {
        command.AddControl(toolsPopup.CommandBar, 1);
      }
    }
    catch(System.ArgumentException)
    {
      //If we are here, then the exception is probably because a command with that
      //  name
      //  already exists. If so there is no need to recreate the command and we can 
      //  safely ignore the exception.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
menuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStrinpItem[] { menuItem1, menuItem2 });
```

And using the GUI builder works by hovering over the menu items and typing in their names:
Open the menu -> hover over the menu item -> click the box that appears -> type in the menu item text -> type in the next menu item text.

Comment: this is not a forms app there is no menuItem object :-(